# Are the observations matched one-to-one after using MatchIt package?

Tags: r, statistics

It might be a trivial question to many of you.

I have matched the treatment observations with a large pool of control observations using the `MatchIt` package in `r` with method `nearest`. After extracting the matched data, should I use independent sample t-test or paired t-test to compare a continuous outcome variable? My understanding is that matching mimics balanced randomization where treatment and control groups are similar in terms of exogenous confounders. However, I've found some tutorials which are using paired t-test after matching. That made me wonder which treatment observation is matched with which control observation? I couldn't find an index variable that may answer this question. Following is a sample code that is similar to what I have used for my data:

```
library("MatchIt")
data("lalonde")
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ re74 + re75 + educ + black + hispan + age, data = lalonde, method = "nearest")
m.data <- match.data(m.out)
t.test(m.data$re78 ~ m.data$treat)
```

One more question, how important is it to use `zelig` after `MatchIt` to estimate ATT (average treatment effect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question about matched pair id: according to `MatchIt` documentation, you can get see Outcomes of Matched Pairs:

```
cbind(lalonde[row.names(m.out$match.matrix),"re78"], lalonde[m.out$match.matrix,"re78"])

             [,1]        [,2]
  [1,]  9930.0460    94.57450
  [2,]  3595.8940  7118.20900
  [3,] 24909.4500  3683.97200
  [4,]  7506.1460 12718.79000
  ....
```

So, you can generate `pair_id` variable for `m.data` as:

```
m.data$pair_id = c(1:185, 1:185)
```

For your second question, once you get `pair_id`, you can use any packages of your choice which can handle matched data.

Comment: @Zhiquiang Wang Thank you so much. This is all I needed.